# Months To date formula not working properly on Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am newbie in Power Bi. I am calculating months to date of a measure.

I have written following DAX formula for that,

`MTD in Sales = CALCULATE([Total Sales], DATESMTD(Dates[Date]) )`

it shows me correct total sales value of this month.But when i make day-wise, it shows me some unrealistic value.[image]

I have attached a screenshots of my result..Please have a look.

I don't understand what wrong are going on? Can you please find out the problem plz?

Answer (score 0):

`DATESMTD(Dates[Date])` is equivalent to:

```
CALCULATETABLE(
    FILTER(
        ALL(Dates[Date]),
        AND(
            Dates[Date] <= MAX(Dates[Date]),
            AND (
                YEAR(Dates[Date]) = YEAR(MAX(Dates[Date])),
                MONTH(Dates[Date]) = MONTH(MAX(Dates[Date]))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This only considers the maximum value of the dates in the external filter context, so for `Tuesday` (today), it will contain every day of the month up to today, for `Monday` (yesterday) it will contain every day of the month up to yesterday and so on. (Assuming that no Sales are linked to future dates).

If you want to further filter this to only include sales that occurred on the given day of the week, I'd suggest altering `MTD in Sales` to:

```
[MTD in Sales] := CALCULATE([Total Sales], DATESMTD(Dates[Date]), Dates[DayOfWeekName])
```

This will additionally filter the included dates to only those with `DayOfWeekName` values present in the external filter context.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mankarse. I had totally wrong idea about MTD. You have cleared my concept. Thanks a lot